# Swift programming: Multiple Positions on Map View

Tags: swift, google-maps, maps

I have a simple problem and I am new to IOS - I want to have multiple GPS streams coming on the same map. Please help as to how could that be done

the current code works:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationmanager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

}

but this only gives me one location.

Comment: Your device can only have one GPS location. What is it you're trying to do? If you're wanting to show other points on the map, use `MKPointAnnotation`.

Comment: thank you for your response. Lets take an example - you and I both have the same application installed on our IOS - we both can see each other's location whenever we open the app. so the application has 2 gps streams - similarly if i need third - I will add the app on their phone. 

The second step is, that if i want to track your location - i can do by selecting you.

Comment: Think of it in a different way - you have a map displayed, and on that map you want to display two locations. The first location is that of the device, so you get the co-ordinates from the device's GPS. The second location is somebody else's position. Where are you getting their co-ordinates from? You cannot access their GPS. The app on their device must write their co-ordinates to a server somewhere. You app then reads these co-ordinates from the server and displays them using a `MKPointAnnotation`. There is no "GPS stream" for the app other than that for the device it is running on.

Comment: That sounds reasonable! So my target would be to use this application to save location of the device periodically to a server. Each device would have a unique name - whenever anyone with the application launches, he/she would be able to see the last updated location on the server - please let me know if the approach is right?

Comment: Exactly. If you don't have a server, you could investigate using Apple's CloudKit.

Comment: I dont, i will see what that does, thank you so much Michael.

Comment: No worries - I will take my comments and add them as an answer so you can close off the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a map displayed, and on that map you want to display two locations.

The first location is that of the device, so you get the co-ordinates from the device's GPS.

The second location is somebody else's position. Where are you getting their co-ordinates from? You cannot access their GPS. The app on their device must write their co-ordinates to a server somewhere. You app then reads these co-ordinates from the server and displays them using a `MKPointAnnotation`. There is no "GPS stream" for the app other than that for the device it is running on.

Similarly, the app on your device must write your own co-ordinates, so it can appear on their app.

If you don't have a server, you could investigate using Apple's CloudKit (for example).